# Ruby stops with implicit no conversion error unless JSON is printed out before parsing

Tags: json, ruby, parsing

I am querying the discord API until there are users. It's paginated and you can get a 1000 at a time.

IF I print out `response.body` by leaving this line in there `p ["BEFORE PARSE", response.body]` the code works well and all the 17 iterations go through.

IF I remove that line then the code throws an error when I call dig on the user `json no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)` cuz one of the user instances in iteration 10 returns ['global', false] instead of a user instance.

What could be the problem?

```
def initialize
  @role_mapping = {}
  @students = {}
  @connection = Faraday.new(
    url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10',
    params: {},
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
      'Authorization' => 'Bot 1234abcd'
    }
  )
end

...

def request_members(guild_id, after = "0", limit = 1000)
  response = connection.get("guilds/#{guild_id}/members") do |req|
    req.params['limit'] = limit
    req.params['after'] = after
  end

  p ["BEFORE PARSE", response.body]
    
  parsed_response = JSON.parse(response.body)

  updated_after = nil
  updated_after = parsed_response[-1]['user']['id'] if parsed_response[-1]

  parsed_response.each do |user|
    user_id = user.dig('user', 'id')

    roles = user['roles'].filter_map do |role_id|
      @role_mapping[role_id] if @role_mapping[role_id]
    end

    if @students[user_id]
      @students[user_id] = @students[user_id] + roles
    else
      @students[user_id] = roles
    end
  end

  request_members(guild_id, updated_after) if updated_after
end
```

Comment: What is `connection`? What class, what gem?

Comment: Updated. It's the faraday gem.

Comment: Must be a coincidence. `response.body` does not look like a method that runs any code. It just fetches Struct data. Therefore what you describe should not be possible. What happens if you replace the `p` line with just `response.body`?

Comment: Also `dig` is a method of the `Hash` class. There is no way you can get a JSON error from calling `dig`. You must be leaving out some code or not reading the error message correctly.